# Create/Edit Form inside index action rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

I have a create/edit form inside a `opinions_controller.rb`. Each opinion has many comments. This comments are done from 2 kind of people (but this don't mean for now).

The problem I have is: "when I submit a new comment (partial form inside a opinion partial) from index action (OpinionsController#index) the whole content of page is re-rendered."

We use `remote: true` for forms, and `create.js.erb`/`update.js.erb` views to manage response.

OpinionsController#index:
[image: index page]

This is a partial from: CommentController#create:
[image: partial comment]

When I click on create for example, The whole index page re-renders (but not refresh page, see the logs):

[image: logs]

But I can't make the re-render stop!

The correct in my opinion is: "When click on create, just render the action CREATE not INDEX from parent page".

Someone knows how can I stop it?

Comment: Ouff, that's hard to follow, please introduce the situation clearly and include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will edit it!

Comment: It is still unclear what you're asking for. Include the problematic code snippet so we can try to help.

Comment: That's the problem Emile I don't know where and why my code re-render index action when I submit a form inside this page!

Comment: It will be even harder for us since the description is confusing and we don't have your code. SO isn't the right place for that kind of debug question. You need to figure out where the bug might come from (in code) and be able to reproduce the problem with a minimal snippet, otherwise, we won't be able to help.

Comment: By searching for a minimal snippet, you may find the bug itself and succeed in fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add latest comment by following js code in create.js.erb/update.js.erb

```
$('.comment-list').append('<%= @latest_comment %>');
```

You need to use HTML DIV element to achieve above.

Ex)

```
<div class='comment-list'>
  comments
</div>
```

You can easily add latest comment to DIV element.

Comment: Thk for your answer, but this is not my problem (we already do that), I've edited the question, please see that ;)